# A having problem when extract txt file in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main() 
{
    string product_name;
    float price;

    ifstream file("shopping.txt");
    
    while(file >> product_name >> price) {
        cout << product_name << ": " << price << " euros" << endl;
    }

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open the file!" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I currently learning C++ , OPP for be specific and came across a problem which ask to extract info from a txt file and print it on the screen

Here the txt file name "shopping.txt"

```
pears       1.23
ham pizza   1.95
salad       0.80
lemonade    1.67
newspaper   2.00
beef        3.52
potatoes    1.52
milk        0.80
```

When I use string varible for the price it works well but because I want to use for calculation, eg total fees , I change it to float type but the program return only the first line of the txt file and stop

I expect this to print out the whole list which has the var price as a float for further calculation

Comment: `ham pizza   1.95` won't do what you want, even with two string variables rather than one string and one float. That isn't two strings; it's *three*. I suspect therein lies your problem.

Comment: You may want to use std::getline into a string and parse the string.

Comment: *"When I use string varible for the price it works well"* -- that's strange. When I tried changing the type of `price` to `string`, I got the output `ham: pizza euros` followed by more lines that look rather wrong (price, colon, food, then "euros"). This is working well??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `file >> product_name` reads a **single** word but on the second line of your file you have `ham pizza` which is two words. This throws the reading off because your code is then going to try and read `pizza` as a floating point value.

There are various ways you could fix it, but honestly the simplest is going to be to change your file to say

```
ham-pizza   1.95
```

Later after you have read the product name you can change any dashes to spaces.